# Why does mogrify output more files than what I gave as input

Tags: video, imagemagick, mogrify

I converted some PDF files to PNG files using:

```
mogrify -background white -alpha off -verbose -density 1000 -resize 1600 -format png ./*.pdf
```

on Microsoft Windows 10 (requires  [Imagemagick](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/index.php)  and  [Ghostscript](https://www.ghostscript.com/download/gsdnld.html) to be installed).

My folder contained before   running mogrify:

[image]

My folder contained *after*   running mogrify:

[image]

How comes `image_00003001-0.png`, `image_00003001-1.png`, and `image_00003001-2.png` have appeared?

Console log:

```
Microsoft Windows [Version 10.0.14393]
(c) 2016 Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

C:\Users\fdernoncourt\Downloads\test\test>mogrify -background white -alpha off -verbose -density 1000 -resize 1600 -format png ./*.pdf
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620r8ZHLol6SeVY%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620m3MK2WrYaV3Y" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620bNrcdEbgPz0C"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620r8ZHLol6SeVY1 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 488596B 0.609u 0:00.614
.\image_0000001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 488596B 0.000u 0:00.003
.\image_0000001.pdf=>.\image_0000001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 416847B 3.469u 0:00.711
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620h9GbXPAw8gLn%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620JtgqmdOva50_" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620BQCg_hCHj5J0"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620h9GbXPAw8gLn1 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 515019B 0.609u 0:00.593
.\image_00001001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 515019B 0.000u 0:00.005
.\image_00001001.pdf=>.\image_00001001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 446212B 3.422u 0:00.685
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620Y3jZ55zTFuuw%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-46204uESOyNRP4d1" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620CSWbMrgy6xKq"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620Y3jZ55zTFuuw1 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 532302B 0.563u 0:00.562
.\image_00002001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 532302B 0.000u 0:00.006
.\image_00002001.pdf=>.\image_00002001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 464289B 3.453u 0:00.763
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620c5A_o-XE8Via%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620GGEzyomwONZe" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620fRieoMrkJnqD"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620c5A_o-XE8Via1 PNG 4000x4000 4000x4000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 129502B 0.188u 0:00.187
C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620c5A_o-XE8Via2 PNG 4000x4000 4000x4000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 135379B 0.188u 0:00.181
C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620c5A_o-XE8Via3 PNG 4000x4000 4000x4000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 138411B 0.188u 0:00.179
.\image_00003001.pdf[0] PDF 4000x4000 4000x4000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 129502B 0.375u 0:00.378
.\image_00003001.pdf[1] PDF 4000x4000 4000x4000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 129502B 0.188u 0:00.195
.\image_00003001.pdf[2] PDF 4000x4000 4000x4000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 129502B 0.000u 0:00.010
.\image_00003001.pdf=>.\image_00003001-0.png[0] PDF 4000x4000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 106061B 4.438u 0:00.833
.\image_00003001.pdf=>.\image_00003001-1.png[1] PDF 4000x4000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 123627B 3.406u 0:00.899
.\image_00003001.pdf=>.\image_00003001-2.png[2] PDF 4000x4000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 125529B 2.422u 0:00.968
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620FJf-uVtE-LBr%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620MXYzETv3mXaj" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620OGD6l6YHmQuE"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620FJf-uVtE-LBr1 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 547857B 0.563u 0:00.570
.\image_00100001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 547857B 0.000u 0:00.004
.\image_00100001.pdf=>.\image_00100001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 460415B 3.438u 0:00.713
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620cNle7W0jNfVy%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620sOtPquz67jjr" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620bwhPST4j8SYu"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620cNle7W0jNfVy1 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 582141B 0.547u 0:00.541
.\image_00200001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 582141B 0.000u 0:00.011
.\image_00200001.pdf=>.\image_00200001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 488440B 3.500u 0:00.691
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620hlI2v4hZKWoN%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620P9fXsO_Rgq46" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620D1uWtiZeLFQ-"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620hlI2v4hZKWoN1 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 598885B 0.563u 0:00.562
.\image_00300001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 598885B 0.000u 0:00.004
.\image_00300001.pdf=>.\image_00300001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 493836B 3.500u 0:00.711
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620XPBkCobwML12%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620LSZUrhBVHovK" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620mnr7WpyafgTx"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620XPBkCobwML121 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 642897B 0.547u 0:00.550
.\image_00400001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 642897B 0.000u 0:00.006
.\image_00400001.pdf=>.\image_00400001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 554808B 3.531u 0:00.725
[ghostscript library 9.21] -q -dQUIET -dSAFER -dBATCH -dNOPAUSE -dNOPROMPT -dMaxBitmap=500000000 -dAlignToPixels=0 -dGridFitTT=2 "-sDEVICE=pngalpha" -dTextAlphaBits=4 -dGraphicsAlphaBits=4 "-r1000x1000"  "-sOutputFile=C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620t1YplpFyLx5h%d" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620CU1rrLSeEcFa" "-fC:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620jaN1roq6k8_0"C:/Users/FDERNO~1/AppData/Local/Temp/magick-4620t1YplpFyLx5h1 PNG 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 8-bit sRGB 626928B 0.641u 0:00.640
.\image_00500001.pdf PDF 7000x7000 7000x7000+0+0 16-bit sRGB 626928B 0.000u 0:00.006
.\image_00500001.pdf=>.\image_00500001.png PDF 7000x7000=>1600x1600 1600x1600+0+0 16-bit sRGB 545850B 3.250u 0:00.771

C:\Users\fdernoncourt\Downloads\test\test>
```

Comment: sounds like that pdf has 3 pages?

Comment: @TomYan only 1.

Comment: Not what ghostscript seem to think though. I think it's hard (if possible) to tell how did it go wrong without the actual pdf in hand. Could be a ghostscript bug, or could be just the pdf being a problematic one.